# Flask Pymongo exception management

Tags: python, flask, pymongo

I have a Flask route defined like so:

```
@app.route('/api/v0.1/getTopPosts', methods = ['POST'])
@auth.login_required
def get_top_posts():
  if not request.json or not 'page' in request.json:
    abort(400)

  resultsPerQuery = 10
  page = int(request.json['page'])
  skip = ( page - 1) * resultsPerQuery;

  postsToReturn = []
  errorDidOccur = False

  #get top posts
  try:
      topPostsReturn = db.collection.find({"isActive":"yes","state":{ "$BAD" : False }}).sort('rank',1).limit(resultsPerQuery).skip(skip)

      for topPost in topPostsReturn:
        postsToReturn.append(db.collection.find_one({'_id':topPost['posts_id']}).copy())

  except pymongo.errors.OperationFailure as e:
      errorDidOccur = True


  if errorDidOccur:
      reply = {
          'reply' : 'failure',
          'error' : e,
          'data' : None
      }
  else:
      reply = {
          'reply' : 'success',
          'error' : None,
          'data' : postsToReturn
      }

  return dumps(reply)
```

I inserted the $BAD to generate an OperationalFailure exception. The problem I have is that 'e' is not JSON serializable. I get:

```
TypeError: OperationFailure(u'database error: invalid operator: $BAD',) is not JSON serializable
```

How do I go about reporting the error back?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
'error' : e.message,
```

instead of

```
'error' : e,
```